# RIP Unshô Ishizuka, Japanese voice actor for Professor Oak, Jet Black, and Joseph Joestar

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Unshô Ishizuka passed away on August 13, 2018. He was [a prolific Japanese voice actor](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0411167/) who voiced many popular characters in anime such as Professor Oak (*Pokémon*), Jet Black (*Cowboy Beebop*), and Joseph Joestar (*JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*). Even if you watched the English dubs and never heard his voice, know that your favorite characters achieved their popularity in Japan thanks to his talents.

[image: Unshô Ishizuka voice actor]

Comment: Not the dad from *Initial D*! No!

Comment: RIP Hohenheim. :-(

Comment: Cowboy BeBop will never be the same for me, now. RIP, Jet!